# What's a word for trust, trustworthy or credibility that starts with the letter "O"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

As the title suggests im after a word that starts with O that means the same as trust, being trustworthy, being credible and other similar words. I need this to complete an acronym I am creating.

The context would be a sentence like, "Can you convey trust?" or "Are you credible" or "Are you trustworthy?", "Can you show credibility?".

Comment: I am creating an acronym and the final letter I need to use is "O". If I can't get a suitable word, ill need to think of a different set of letters entirely and therefore a new acronym

Comment: The acronym is describing a procedure, part of that procedure is having trust/credibility.

Comment: Thesaurus.com has a number of pages for [*trustworthy*](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/trustworthy/).

Included in those are

* open
* on the level
* objective,

along with a few others beginning with *o* which seem even less suitable to me. I don't think you will find a word which means what you want. That said, I didn't look up synonyms of *credible;* there may be something there. **What have you already looked up and discarded?**

Comment: That's weird because the first place I went to was Thesaurus.com but I never got those results. On the level isn't too bad.

Comment: You have to look through a number of pages of synonyms of synonyms for suggestions which match the original word. You do need to show your research, what you found, why you rejected things and what sort of word you're looking for (here, it's not even clear what part of speech you want).

Comment: 'Onest is  possible depending how serious the acronym has to be.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a stretch, but **Oath** is around the same area as your descriptions. According to the [Oxford Definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/oath):

> 1. A solemn promise, often invoking a divine witness, regarding one's future action or behaviour.
>
>    > 1.1 A sworn declaration, such as the promise to tell the truth, in a court of law.

Taking an oath could prove someone to be trustworthy and credible, which is what you're after. Without more detail, I unaware if it applies to your needs.

Comment: The context would be a sentence like, "Can you convey trust?" or "Are you credible" or "Are you trustworthy?", "Can you show credibility?". Replacing those sentences with oath don't really work. eg "Are you oath?" Is there another variation of oath that will fit this situation?

Comment: @zoonosis You could very easily say "Would you take an oath to uphold <xyz>?"

Answer (score 0):

**[Original](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/original)** can be synonymous with ***credible*** or ***trustworthy*** in the sense of  [not secondary, derivative, or imitative](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/original).